# Hidden or empty content into a rar file?

Tags: passwords, rar

I have a password rar file that is 73.2MB size, but when I enter the password and open it, the rar file is empty, no content. How is it possible?

What can I do to see the content?

Comment: Are you sure that the file is not corrupt?

Comment: no it's not....
i've downloaded it again but the same thing...
It gave me just an error "No files to extract"

Comment: Have you tried a different extractor? Have tried other computers or operating systems?

Comment: yes with 7 zip but same problem :(

Comment: In Properties - Archive menu, appears 0% in left side, and Total Files: 0

Comment: Can you use a hex editor such as [this one](http://www.hexedit.com) to open the file and post a screenshot of the contents here? See if there's any data inside the RAR, if if it's just a fake of some kind with all 0s.

Comment: [link](http://s14.postimage.org/5ze4545pd/ssss.png)

Comment: If the contents of the file are not sensitive (unlikely since it's password protected) you might want to put it in a public place like DropBox and give us the download link to look at the file.

Comment: i will try, but are you sure you can look at this file if it's password protect? [link](http://www.girlshare.ro/32225959.7)

Answer (score 1):

I usually have hidden files in Windows Eplorer enabled, so I haven't seen something similar. Try enabling hidden files. In Vista, 7 and 8 this is done from Control Panel, Folder Options. If still there is nothing there you might have used a wrong password. Make sure you type the correct password to unlock the RAR archive.

Comment: the pass is correct, 'cause the file open alright, without any error

Comment: pass is gu8c32i9oa871z